# Updating form state using Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-state-management

I'm developing an application and currently, i'm trying to convert the normal react code to redux toolkit code. Specifically, i'm trying to make the conversion process for the register component. This component includes a form with several fields in order to get the user registered on the application. Now, I'm trying to update the form state using the redux toolkit library. Regarding that, I have a few questions:

1. What would be the most optimal way to work with the forms in react?
2. Let's say, i still want to work with the redux toolkit library for this component, i am facing some problems with it. I am not able to access the state using the useSelector hook (it returns the initial state (initially, and then returns nothing but the state is getting updated which i verified through devtools). And what i currently want to do is **dynamically** check whether the password and confirm password fields match and if not, set the error, otherwise keep it an empty string. But i'm not able to do this. I could definitely access the state on the button click or submit but am not able to while the user types in the fields (i.e. dynamically).

Register.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useReducer } from 'react'
import { createBrowserHistory } from '@remix-run/router';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Header';
import { userActions, UserState } from '../features/userSlice';
import { store } from '../store/store';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';


const Register = (props: any) => {


    const error = useSelector((state:UserState)=>state.error);  
    

    const state:UserState = store.getState().user;

    const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(()=>{
       console.log('updated state: ', store.getState().user.error);
    })


    const handleRegister = async (e:any) => {
        // debugger;
        e.preventDefault();

        const state:UserState = store.getState().user;
        console.log(state);
    }



    return (

        <div>
            <Header/>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <form className="container p-3">
                        <div className="row mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="name" className="col-form-label col-sm-2 text-wrap">
                                Name:
                            </label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10">
                                <input onChange={(e)=>store.dispatch(userActions.updateName(e.target.value))} type="text" className="form-control" id="name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="phone" className="col-form-label col-sm-2 text-wrap">
                                Phone:
                            </label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10">
                                <input onChange={(e)=>store.dispatch(userActions.updatePhone(e.target.value))} type="tel" className="form-control" id="phone" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="email" className="col-form-label col-sm-2 text-wrap">
                                Email:
                            </label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10">
                                <input onChange={(e)=>store.dispatch(userActions.updateEmail(e.target.value))} type="email" className="form-control" id="email" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="password" className="col-form-label col-sm-2 text-wrap">
                                Password:
                            </label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10">
                                <input onChange={(e)=>store.dispatch(userActions.updatePassword(e.target.value))} type="password" className="form-control" id="password" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="confirm-password" className="col-form-label col-sm-2 text-wrap">
                                Confirm Password:
                            </label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10">
                                <input onChange={(e)=>store.dispatch(userActions.updateConfimrPass(e.target.value))} type="password" className="form-control" id="confirm-password" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="dob" className="col-form-label col-sm-2 text-wrap">
                                Date of Birth
                            </label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10">
                                <input onChange={(e)=>store.dispatch(userActions.updateDOB(e.target.value))} type="date" className="form-control" id="dob" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="address" className="col-form-label col-sm-2 text-wrap">
                                Address:
                            </label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10">
                                <textarea
                                    onChange={(e)=>{store.dispatch(userActions.updateAddress(e.target.value))}}
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name="address"
                                    id="address"
                                ></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row mb-3">
                            <label className="col-form-label col-sm-2 text-wrap" htmlFor="gender">
                                Gender:
                            </label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10 d-flex">
                                <div className="form-check me-3">
                                    <input
                                        className="form-check-input"
                                        name="gender"
                                        id="male"
                                        type="radio"
                                        value="Male"
                                        onChange={(e)=>{store.dispatch(userActions.updateGender(e.target.value))}}
                                    />
                                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="male">Male</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-check">
                                    <input
                                        className="form-check-input"
                                        name="gender"
                                        id="female"
                                        type="radio"
                                        value="Female"
                                        onChange={(e)=>store.dispatch(userActions.updateGender(e.target.value))}
                                    />
                                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="female">Female</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="row mb-3">
                            <label className="col-form-label col-sm-2 text-wrap" htmlFor="">City:</label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10">
                                <select onChange={(e)=>store.dispatch(userActions.updateCity(e.target.value))} className="form-select">
                                    <option selected>Select city</option>
                                    <option value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
                                    <option value="Gurgaon">Gurgaon</option>
                                    <option value="Shimla">Shimla</option>
                                    <option value="Manali">Manali</option>
                                    <option value="New Delhi">New Delhi</option>
                                    <option value="Noida">Noida</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-evenly">
                            <button onClick={handleRegister} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                            <button id="reset" type="reset" className="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className='col-12 text-center'>
                    {/* <span>{error}</span> */}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    )
}

export default Register;
```

userSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
    

export interface UserState{ 
    loading: boolean;
    error: string;
    data: {
        name: string,
        phone: string,
        email: string,
        password: string,
        confirmPass: string,
        dob: string,
        address: string,
        gender: string,
        city: string
    };
}

const initialState:UserState = {
    loading: false,
    error: '',
    data: {
        name: '',
        phone: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPass: '',
        dob: '',
        address: '',
        gender: '',
        city: ''
    }
}


const postData = createAsyncThunk('users/postData', (data:Object)=>{
    axios
        .post('http://localhost:3001/signup', data)
        .then((res)=>console.log(res))
        .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
})



const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateName: (state,action)=>{
            state.data.name = action.payload
        },
        updatePhone: (state,action)=>{
            state.data.phone = action.payload
        },
        updateEmail: (state,action)=>{
            state.data.email = action.payload
        },
        updatePassword: (state,action)=>{
            state.data.password = action.payload;

        },
        updateConfimrPass: (state,action)=>{
            state.data.confirmPass = action.payload;
            if(state.data.password !== state.data.confirmPass) state.error = 'Passwords do not match';
            else state.error = '';
        },
        updateDOB: (state,action)=>{
            state.data.dob = action.payload
        },
        updateAddress: (state,action)=>{
            state.data.address = action.payload
        },
        updateGender: (state,action)=>{
            state.data.gender = action.payload
        },
        updateCity: (state,action)=>{
            state.data.city = action.payload
        },
        // submitData: (state,action)=>{

        // }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) =>{
        builder.addCase(postData.fulfilled, (state,action)=>{
            
        })
        builder.addCase(postData.pending, (state)=>{
            //set loading to true
        })
        builder.addCase(postData.rejected, (state,action)=>{
            
        })
    }
})


export const userReducer = userSlice.reducer;
export const userActions = userSlice.actions;
```

store.ts

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {userReducer, userActions} from '../features/userSlice';


export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userReducer
    }
});
```

App.tsx

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Register from './Components/Register'
import Login from './Components/Login';
import UserDashboard from './Components/UserDashboard';
import DashboardNav from './Components/DashboardNav';
import CreateEvent from './Components/CreateEvent';
import EventCard from './Components/EventCard';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux/es/exports';
import { store } from './store/store';


function App() {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/user-dashboard" element={<UserDashboard/>} />
          <Route path="/create-event" element={<CreateEvent />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Picture of Redux DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a4tj.png)

I've been stuck on this for a few days and i really need some guidance/insight. Hoping for a reply soon. Thanks.